# Numbers whose decimal expansions are their own continued fractions.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion, continued-fractions

I was wondering if there is some positive real $x<1$ with non-terminating decimal expansion $b_1b_2b_3\dots$ where $b_1\neq0$ which also satisfies
$$x=\dfrac1{b_1b_2\dots b_i+\dfrac1{b_{i+1}b_{i+2}\dots b_{j} + \dfrac1{b_{j+1}\dots b_k + \dfrac1{\ddots}}}}$$
Where $b_gb_{g+1}\dots$ is *not* a product, rather some number with decimal expansion $b_gb_{g+1}\dots$.  For example, if $b_1=2$ and $b_2=4$, then $b_1b_2$ is the number $24$, not $8$.

I have found a family of rational $x$ which satisfy the above. They are:
$$\frac13 = \frac1{3+\dfrac1{333333\dots + \dfrac1{\text{doesn't matter what goes here.}}}}$$
$$\frac1{33} = \frac1{3+\dfrac1{03 + \dfrac1{03+\dfrac1{03030303030303\dots + \dfrac1{\text{doesn't matter what goes here.}}}}}}$$
And so forth.

**My question:** can we prove/disprove the existence of an irrational such $x$? Can we determine the value of such an $x$, if it exists? Also, does my family of rational $x$ being $\frac13,\frac1{33}\dots$ cover all rational solutions?

Comment: I think your second example is for $10/33$, not $1/33$.